# error while adding new value for dropdownlist in javascript

Tags: javascript

i need to add same value for two dropdowns in js
code is as follows

```
 var opt1 = new Option("All", 0);
 document.getElementById('ddlfromGroupCountry').optons[0] = opt1;
 document.getElementById('ddlFromCountry').optons[0] = opt1;
```

i am using same Option variable i.e opt1 for adding value to both dropdowns

in second line getting following error

```
htmlfile: Invalid argument.
```

any suggestions

thanks in advance

Comment: Is "optons" a typo? Did you mean options?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that works in plain javascript, but I'd recommend using some library like jQuery to do all the heavy work for you:

```
var r = document.createElement('option'), 
    select = document.getElementById('your-element-id');
r.value = 'val';
r.innerHTML = 'Test';
select.insertBefore(r, select.childNodes[0]);
```

​